# Trapping invalid incoming requests in a web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I have a web service that is going to be used for generic calls to it for logging the requests sent. I want to know if there is a simple way of trapping all incoming requests (whether valid or not)?

Adding breakpoints in the constructor only works if the request is valid, I want to trap all incoming to the url whether valid or not, is there an event I can add to do this?

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public WebService1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("here");
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: And what constitutes a "valid request"?

Comment: Usually in classic ASP.Net you would need to tap to application events in the Global.asax `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` [blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Jun/18/How-do-ASPNET-Application-Events-Work). An other option would be a [custom HttpModule](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/implement-custom-httphandler-and-custom-httpmodule).

Comment: Or google SoapExtension - can't find a suitable dupe right now.